# How can I apply a style to element if the user came to website using a link with an anchor/hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let’s say I’ve put, somewhere on the internet, a link to my website. To be specific, it was a URL with an anchor/hash linking to a part of an article, like this: `http://example.com/article/#subsection`.

Now, if someone came through this link to my website, how can I trigger CSS/JS to make some action?

In my particular case, I want to add a style to the `<div>` with an `id` of `subsection` when someone uses the link containing `#subsection`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't! You could check the unreliable referrer to see where the user is coming from, but there's no way to know if the user clicked a link unless you add something special to that link, as in a hash or querystring.

Comment: You can't. The URL fragment is not sent to your server and isn't accessible through `document.referrer`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use hash only instead of (well, probably in addition to) GET parameters? `http://example.com/article/?remote=yes#subsection`

Comment: I don't know anything about GET parameters, but for me http://example.com/article/#subsection just looks nicer. Are there any drawbacks of using it instead GET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given IE9 and later, this is possible entirely through [the `:target` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget):

```css
#subsection:target {
    …
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're trying to do is to highlight a section on your page that matches the hash value in the current URL (which isn't entirely clear from the wording in your question) and you want to support a wide range of older browsers, then you can do something like this:

The hash value is not sent to the server so you would have to apply a change in client-side javascript.  You can do that by adding a class to the object that matches the hash name when your page loads:

```
<script>
var id = window.location.hash.slice(1);
if (id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    if (obj) {
        obj.className += " specialStyle";
    }
}
</script>
```

Or, using jQuery:

```
<script>
if (window.location.hash.length > 1) {
    $(window.location.hash).addClass("specialStyle");
}
</script>
```

These scripts must be located anywhere after the elements you wish to add the class to or protected from executing until the DOM is loaded using something like `$(document).ready()`, though the sooner the script can run, the sooner the new style will show.

---

It's unclear to me whether the XSS vulnerability mentioned in the comments is still an issue in jQuery now or not, but you could either using the plain javascript version (which does not contain this vulnerability) or further protect against that in the jQuery version with something like this:

```
<script>
if (window.location.hash.length > 1) {
    $(window.location.hash.replace(/[<>]/g, "")).addClass("specialStyle");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, both scripts work like they should. I wish I could make it an answer too.

Comment: Fun fact: [this was once a vulnerability in jQuery!](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9521)

Comment: Forgot to ask, why second script is in if statement if it works without it? **EDIT** Ok, now I know, it's because if there's no if statement then the changes don't apply when you link the #subsection from inside the page

Comment: Forget my last comment and edit, it's not because of that. So the question remains.

Comment: @Dominik - Simply because it seemed safer to me to NOT execute the jQuery if there was no hash value other than `#`.  If you feel like testing jQuery to verify that `$("#").addClass()` is harmless, you're welcome to remove the `if` statement.  I found it easier and more foolproof to only execute the jQuery if there was indeed a hash value present than to rely on the undocumented behavior when supplying a malformed selector.

Comment: Added some info about the XSS security vulnerability.